# Maintain div height, change image width - allow for image bleeding

Tags: html, css

I have a situation where a `div` `height` can be set. Once the `height` is set, the image `height` within the `div` will remain the same. If the `width` changes (from different viewports), the image view will decrease in `width`, but the image should not scale with the different viewports. I have demonstrated this with the dotted line in the diagram representing the image bleed

[image: viewport-representation]

The `div` and `img` should always be centred horizontally and vertically in relation to the image bleed.

I have tried `position: relative;` on the `div` and `position: absolute;` with no luck

Comment: Post some lines of code so we can better understand your issue

Comment: I posted my answer, but as @Ruber stated, please provide more code in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hide the overflow** on the image container and **center the image vertically and horizontally** while **maintaining the original size**.

```css
.img-container {
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.img-container img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>I Am A Beautiful Image</h1>
<div class="img-container">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1039/1920/1200" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: This is very accurate for my needs. This is my accepted answer. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try using the image as background image with specific size.

```
.foo {
  background-image      : url("/url.gif");
  background-repeat     : no-repeat;
  background-attachment : fixed;           // optional
  background-position   : center;
  background-size       : 700px 400px;    // width height
}
```